# Can I choose one of the proxies when running maven?

Tags: maven

I setup few proxies in "/.m2/settings.xml".

Is there any way to choose one specific proxy when I running "mvn clean install" ?

Or I can only comment/un-comment the proxies to use a specific one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't understand why you would want to do it, if what you are looking for is to have multiple settings for proxy but you will only need one, I believe you can do it by using profile.

something like:

```
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>proxy1</id>
      <properties>
        <proxyHost>host-1</proxyHost>
        <proxyPort>1234</proxyPort>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>proxy2</id>
      <properties>
        <proxyHost>host-2</proxyHost>
        <proxyPort>1234</proxyPort>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <host>${proxyHost}</host>        
      <port>${proxyPort}</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Then when you use mvn, simply do `mvn -P proxy1`

(Haven't actually tried that but I think it should work :P )